# Strange behaviour when using FILTER to filter a different table with no direct relationship?

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have two facts tables, `First` and `Second`, and two dimension tables, `dimTime` and `dimColour`.

Fact table `First` looks like this:

[image]

and facet table `Second` looks like this:

[image]

Both dim-tables have 1:* relationships to both fact tables and the filtering is one-directional (from dim to fact), like this:

[image]

```
 dimColour[Color] 1 -> * First[Colour]
 dimColour[Color] 1 -> * Second[Colour]
 dimTime[Time] 1 -> * First[Time]
 dimTime[Time] 1 -> * Second[Time_]
```

Adding the following measure, I would expect the FILTER-functuion not to have any affect on the calculation, since `Second` does not filter `First`, right?

```
Test_Alone = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( First[Amount] );
    First[Alone] = "Y";
    FILTER(
        'Second';
        'Second'[Colour]="Red"
    )
)
```

So this should evaluate to 7, since only two rows in `First` have [Alone] = "Y" with values 1 and 6 and that there is no direct relationship between First and Second. However, this evaluates to 6. If I remove the FILTER-function argument in the calculate, it evaluates to 7.

There are thre additional measures in the pbix-file attached which show the same type of behaviour.

> How is filtering one fact table which has no direct relationship to a second fact table affecting the calculation done on the second table?

Ziped Power BI-file: [PowerBIFileDownload](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TR6fR78zYJ7y_XtuH7Mg-C6dzZ2Fkb8k/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating the table reference `'Second'` produces a table that includes the columns in both the `Second` table, as well as those in all the (transitive) parents of the `Second` table.

In this case, this is a table with all of the columns in `dimColour`, `dimTime`, `Second`.

You can't see this if you just run:

```
evaluate 'Second'
```

as when 'evaluate' returns the results to the user, these "Parent Table" (or "Related") columns are not included.

Even so, these columns are certainly present.
When a table is converted to a row context, these related columns become available via `RELATED`.
See the following queries:

```
evaluate FILTER('Second', ISBLANK(RELATED(dimColour[Color])))

evaluate 'Second' order by RELATED(dimTime[Hour])
```

Similarly, when arguments to `CALCULATE` are used to update the filter context, these hidden "Related" columns are not ignored; hence, they can end up filtering `First`, in your example. You can see this, by using a function that strips the related columns, such as `INTERSECT`:

```
Test_ActuallyAlone = CALCULATE (
    SUM ( First[Amount] ),
    First[Alone] = "Y",
    //This filter now does nothing, as none of the columns in Second
    //have an impact on 'SUM ( First[Amount] )'; and the related columns
    //are removed by the INTERSECT.
    FILTER(
        INTERSECT('Second', 'Second')
        'Second'[Colour]="Red"
    )
)
```

(See these resources that describe the "Expanded Table"
(this is an alternative but equivalent explanation of this behaviour)

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/expanded-tables-in-dax/

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/context-transition-and-expanded-tables/

)

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming this is the answer I'm looking for. I'll mark it as correct when I've studied, and understood the concepts. Cheers,